# How is the id of collection selected in Cosmos DB?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm new to CosmosDB. I've created a collection and added there an object that has an `id` field and some text value. The `id` field in my object is set to some random uuid.

```
{
    "id": "2cdbf85b-43cf-415a-bfec-512c0ce2bf4b",
    "someTextValue": "my text value",
}
```

In database now I see that CosmosDb created my entity and assigned to it an `id` that is the same as I provided in my object.

[image]

When adding this entity I set `disableAutomaticIdGeneration` to `false`

```
client.createDocument(collectionLink, myEntity, null, false)
```

Can someone tell my why the `id` of the database entity remains the same? I expected to have a randomly generated `id` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id is already randomly generated because you set `disableAutomaticIdGeneration` as `False`.

In below pic, the first `id` is the id of document, the second `/id` is the partition key value.

[image]

Since you set the partition key as `/id`, so the id value `"2cdb...."` is the value of partition key value for this document.

Let me say that if you set partition key as e.g. `/name`, then your document shows in the data explorer will looks like:

[image]

Comment: Does it mean that `id` of the whole entity in database that we see at the top left corner of your last picture, `2` in this case, is always equal to the id in the object (top center red frame)

Comment: @Vitalii Yes,that's the id of this single document.And it's unique in this collection.

Comment: @Vitalii Any conflict with your requirements?because it's the normal feature of cosmos db.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if `id` in my object is always the same as id that CosmosDB adds to this entity. Maybe it's the same object. 
I need to make search by id later and I want to figure out if I need to search by id from my object or by id from Cosmos

Comment: @Vitalii Maybe i get your concern,you worry about whether the id of object you created and the id shows in the cosmos db data explorer are totally different things,am i right? The answer is no! No two types id,only one. They are totally one thing.  If you query the id '2', that exactly refer to the document i paste in my answer. That's the unique id of this document in the entire collection. Hope i'm clear here  on this.

Comment: Exaclty, I was asking myself if it was the same or not and if I could perform search of it. Now I understand that it's just a visual interface.
Thanks a lot!